# Resetting WordPress post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a page ID before and after a post loop, the page ID is displaying correctly before the loop, but when I try and display it after the loop it just displays the last post ID of the loop.

I've tried using all of the following to reset the loop and none seem to work:

```
wp_reset_postdata()
wp_reset_query()
rewind_posts()
```

The loop code is:

```
<?php 

echo 'Shows the page ID (correct)=' . $post->ID;

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'accommodation',
'posts_per_page' => '9999',
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
while($wp_query->have_posts()) :    
$wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>

<?php endwhile;
else :
esc_html_e('No bookings','sohohotel');
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

echo 'Shows the ID of the last post in the loop (not correct)=' . $post->ID; ?>
```

Note I'm using WP_Query and not query_posts, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: And a simple `$letsStoreThisValueBecauseWeWillNeedItLater = $post->ID;` would not be able to solve your problem …?

Comment: you can keep the ID in a variable. SO, you can use it before and after

Comment: Thanks! Why didn't I think of that... sometimes the best solution is the simplest

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
while($wp_query->have_posts()) :    
$wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<option value="<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else :
esc_html_e('No bookings','sohohotel');
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't make any difference unfortunately